# XML Drawable from String

Tags: android, string, drawable

Is that possible to make **XML drawable** from a **String** "TEXT" and show it as a background?

WHY?

I have a **Linear layout** which include Text's and I want to use a text shadow as a guide in the background and as I want to use many languages for my App I don't want to lose a lots of time making images in many languages!

Thanks!

**Update:**
text shadow: I mean transparent text as a background... I want this text change when the user change the language.

[image]

As you know we can make a drawable from a shape or color or stroke or whatever.

My question is can we make a drawable from a string with XML.

For example instead of using this Code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<stroke
    android:width="2.0px"
    android:color="@color/stroke_main" />

<corners android:radius="360px" />
```

To get a stroke, use this one:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

<string
    android:string="@string/something" />
```

It sounds very crazy but it might be useful.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29 ?

Answer (score -1):

Use a TextView and string resources. Set alpha on the TextView